# Why does "d1j" delete two lines in vim?

Tags: vim, command

The `d{motion}` command seems to work inconsistently:

```
d1j  " deletes 2 lines to the bottom
d1l  " deletes 1 character to the right
```

Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: This is indeed an excellent question about how vim works.

Comment: Now that you mention, yeah, it inconsistent. If you enable relative numbering in 7.3+ (which I strongly recommend) you can see that the current line is 0 and the lines after/before it are starting with 1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you start a motion and you are in operator pending mode, your motion will be either inclusive or exclusive, and either characterwise or linewise (linewise motions are always inclusive).

`j` is a linewise inclusive motion. Probably you want to try `dvj` or `dgj` (the latter one works with screen lines).

See `:help operator`. You can force motions to be linewise, characterwise or blockwise with V, v or CTRL-V respectively.

Comment: Didn't know that one! Great tip :)

Answer (score 4):

It is *not actually* inconsistent. I guess you were looking for

- delete one line: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (which is a *command*)
- delete one line *down*: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> (or short <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>). This is *an operator with a motion*)

The remaining surprising bits are due to vim's notion of linewise, blockwise and characterwise motions, which are really just abstractions to allow Vim to **Do The Right Thing** or **Do What You Expect** when operating on selections.

---

Like @Benoit said, `d` is operator that takes a motion.

`2j` being linewise, it will *move* two lines down, covering 3 lines.

Note how, if you would like some visual clues with that, you can set the `rn` option

```
:se relativenumber
```

This will cause relative linenumbering to be shown in the left 'gutter' of the editor. These numbers can be used as 'addresses' and do what you expect when you do 'd12j' or 'd12k'

I recommend getting acquainted with the `text object` motions before getting used to this, by the way. Many times, text objects are much more precise (and often work in character mode, only degrading to linewise selections in appropriate conditions)